# Почему нужна или не нужна запятая перед "или"?

Tags: запятые, или

Этот шаг может потребоваться, если вы используете нестандартную конфигурацию сети. Например, если ваш сервер работает под управлением NAT или ваша политика сети блокирует некоторые порты, используемые системными службами.

Answer (score 1):

Без общего слова "например" всё равно запятая бы не была нужна.

> *Если ваш сервер работает под управлением NAT или **(если)** ваша политика сети блокирует некоторые порты, используемые системными службами.*

Здесь два однородных придаточных, связанных союзом "или". Подробнее об этом [у Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139) (§ 35, п. 3). Другое дело, что у нас нет главной части, но второе предложение можно считать продолжением главной части первого: *Этот шаг может потребоваться...*

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере части ССП имеют общее вводное слово "например". Поэтому запятая не ставится.

**Правило:**

В сложносочиненном предложении с одиночными союзами *и, да* (в значении «и»), *или, либо* запятая не ставится в следующих случаях: если части сложносочиненного предложения имеют **общее вводное слово**, общий обособленный член или общую, поясняемую ими, часть сложного предложения: **Словом, время уже истекло и пора было уходить; Вопреки предсказаниям синоптиков, небо уже прояснилось и дождь перестал; Было у Анны необъяснимое ощущение: еще чуть-чуть и вся эта история кончится (Щерб.); Останавливаться было нельзя: ноги засасывало и следы наливались водой (Пауст.).**

См.: [ПАС](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133).